# Typescript's TypeGuard lost in enumerator

Tags: typescript

Looking at the following code, I don't understand why `filter.formatter` (in the penultimate line) could be undefined since I have checked it's presence before:

```js
type Filter = {
    formatter?: {
        index: number,
        func: (value: string) => void
    }
}

const filter: Filter = {
    formatter: {
        index: 1,
        func: (v) => {
            return `Label: ${v}`
        }
    }
}

const data = [['foo', 'bar']]

if (filter.formatter) {
    data[filter.formatter.index].forEach(d => {
        filter.formatter.func(d) // <-- `formatter` is possibly undefined
    })
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATlAvFA3gKCvqAMwHsUBbAQ2GRQH4AubPAluAOwBMIAPRtgVzIAjVABpmLfIX5sAxowAUANwoJ+ERgGdgKdgHMAlBgB8UJcTgcJUAL447OWcTbaiiGo3hJUGJixLkVB5+kvjsXLxQAIzioVIy8lDKRuimuHGSKBDA-ChsUAAGADIUIgiMACRYSjYF1ix2DfY4js6uHFQUvgDa3QDkJMR9olB9QhQofQC6Uy1whEmE7qgAdAGU1KhG6QQdwBTdS94oa6QbNCvhPFOnKACiFLIAFgocJiGhRxfrQavScq8DNYbECbEA)

## Update 1

As @CRice mentionend in the comment, this doesn't happen in `for`-loops. But I still wonder why?

[Updated TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATlAvFA3gKCvqAMwHsUBbAQ2GRQH4AubPAluAOwBMIAPRtgVzIAjVABpmLfIX5sAxowAUANwoJ+ERgGdgKdgHMAlBgB8UJcTgcJUAL447OWcTbaiiGo3hJUGJixLkVB5+kvjsXLxQAIzioVIy8lDKRuimuHGSKBDA-ChsUAAGADIUIgiMACRYSjYF1ix2DfY4js6uHFQUvgDa3QDkJMR9olB9QhQofQC6Uy1whEmE7qgAdAGU1KhG6QQBSQjZUHC+AAwA3EdQADxQHcAU3UveKGukGzQr4TxTKwdsesAABYXOAAalB23qu2WL3WQVW0jkCjuDyeHzhmxeX24U26cCmBmsdhsQA)

Comment: I believe it's because it appears inside a different function than where the check took place. You won't run into the same problem if you use a regular `for/of` loop. I'd recommend just using the non-null assertion operator `!` in cases like this. ie: `filter.formatter!.func(d)`

Comment: Whoa, non-null-assertion-operator, never heard of it, thanks! Yes, it doesn't happen in a for loop, but it would be interesting why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-write the code like this to better understand the error.

```
if (filter.formatter) {
    const itemConsumer = (d: string) => { filter.formatter.func(d) };
    data[filter.formatter.index].forEach(itemConsumer);
}

// both are the same

const itemConsumer = (d: string) => { filter.formatter.func(d) };
if (filter.formatter) {
    data[filter.formatter.index].forEach(itemConsumer);
}
```

Here in `itemConsumer`, you just capture the reference to `filter` but not its actual value.
Therefore, `filter.formatter` could become null before `itemConsumer` is executed.

It's not the case with the `for` loop because you don't create a new function for it, so you use filter value and the compiler can be sure that `filter.formatter` cannot be undefined.

If you want to know more about this, there is a [serie of books](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) about JS and one dedicated to [scope and closure](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/README.md)

Comment: Thanks! Is this some kind of hoisting?

Comment: No, I just moved the declaration outside the `if` to show you that the condition wasn't relevant inside the `itemConsumer`. It's just a matter of value vs reference. When you write the function, it will only take use the reference and it won't take a snapshot of the value. I added a reference to a series of book on JS if you want to understand better